# save data in mysql through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I m trying to send data value in database using ajax but it's not working. please any one help me.
I m trying to send data value in database using ajax but it's not working. please any one help me.

form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="send_value" action="form.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name">
        <input type="text" name="address" value="" id="address">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="save">
    </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#save').click(function() {
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var address = $('#address').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,        
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    data: { name: name, address: address},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('data has been stored to database');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and php file

```
<?php 
include('DataModel.php');

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax_test");
if (!$con) 
{
    die();
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`name`, `address`) VALUES ($name,$address) ";
$query = mysqli_query($sql,$con);
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo json_encode($fetch);
 ?>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting? Check your browser console for Js errors.

Comment: do you have any error message ? do you have tried to print something in your die() in order to see if your connection is up ? do you have tried to echo your $sql query ?

Comment: You need to read up on sql injection and prepared statements. And you don't fetch rows after an insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are missing around the query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`name`, `address`) VALUES ('$name', '$address')";
```

You should also use prepared statements but in the very very least please escape your strings before passing them into the query

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
```

Lest you encounter bugs with addresses or names containing single quotes or leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot the quotes here

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`name`, `address`) VALUES ('$name','$address') ";
```

Or you can bind param like this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `test`(`name`, `address`) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $address);
$stmt->execute();
```